# Return all items from dynamodb ordered by date boto

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am attempting to return all items from a dynamodb table with results ordered by date. The tables structure is:

| ID | Date | Category | Email | Errors | IsRead | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

With ID as the primary key and date defined as the sort key.

As I understand it, a scan() operation cannot be ordered so I am attempting to utilise an open query instead.

I have been able to construct a query that can easily return a particular ID but I am unable to find examples that simply allow a query to return all, possibly using a wildcard?

```
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('_id').eq('e2c0cad8-7630-48c6-8fc3-6b579d5ca021'))
```

Is there an approach that will simply allow a query based on a key that can return an ordered list without requiring a specific filter?

Comment: No, not possible. Your client code needs to scan and retrieve all items and then do the sorting on the client. If you need to do this often then dynamodb is the wrong database for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since date is defined as the sort key, this should be possible using a GraphQL call.  Instead of Query or Scan, try using [ExecuteStatement](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.execute_statement).  My Python is a little rusty, but basically something like this:

```
response = client.execute_statement(
    Statement='SELECT * FROM "TABLE_NAME" WHERE "_id" = "e2c0cad8-7630-48c6-8fc3-6b579d5ca021" ORDER BY date DESC',
    Parameters=[
        {
            ...
        },
    ],
    ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL'
)
```

From what I remember, these calls are a little lighter on the RCU/WCU consumption as well.  Double check that with the ReturnConsumedCapacity on the response though.

*The DyanamoDB UI also has the built-in PartiQL editor to help with building these queries.*